# To find commonality/characteristics of in a group of lists

Tags: python, list

A group of lists of equal length (strings as elements). I want to find out their commonality/characteristics.

Let’s call them “good” lists - I want to find out what makes a “good” list.

A thinking is to output all 3-element combination from each list, then summarize the occurrences of the 3-element to rank them.

For example, “D” and “N” and “T” appeared 4 times. It may conclude that, when “D” and “N” and “T” appear in a list, it is a “good” list.

The same method can apply to 4-element combinations, 5-element combinations (when the many lists are very long).

What would be a better solution?

```
import itertools
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

s = [
['O', 'V', 'R', 'M', 'Y'],
['I', 'Q', 'L', 'J', 'A'],
['M', 'I', 'Q', 'N', 'G'],
['Y', 'M', 'R', 'Q', 'Z'],
['D', 'X', 'C', 'Q', 'N'],
['B', 'O', 'Q', 'E', 'V'],
['V', 'M', 'J', 'G', 'R'],
['M', 'T', 'L', 'I', 'Z'],
['Y', 'H', 'A', 'V', 'L'],
['O', 'T', 'D', 'N', 'E'],
['D', 'N', 'T', 'I', 'G'],
['T', 'Q', 'H', 'I', 'P'],
['F', 'T', 'D', 'W', 'N'],
['F', 'Z', 'H', 'E', 'X'],
['E', 'Z', 'R', 'K', 'J'],
['P', 'C', 'U', 'D', 'F'],
['N', 'I', 'Y', 'U', 'E'],
['T', 'N', 'D', 'L', 'V'],
['D', 'Z', 'I', 'P', 'X'],
['H', 'L', 'C', 'P', 'Y']]

summary = []
for each in s:
    all_combinations =  [comb for comb in combinations(each, 3)]  # unique combinations only

    for a in all_combinations:
        summary.append('-'.join(sorted(a)))

print (Counter(summary))
```

Output:

```
Counter({'D-N-T': 4, 'M-R-V': 2, 'M-R-Y': 2.....})
```

Comment: Are you asking "what would make a good algorithm / heuristic for determining a good list"? Or are you asking for a way to implement your suggested analysis of the lists?

Comment: @MatBailie, thank you for your comment. I am asking "what would make a good algorithm / heuristic for determining a good list".

Answer (score 0):

I think I would make use of an sql database to do this (sqlite in the examples below). You could create a table with two columns `element` and `list` (both primary keys). You would populate it with the elements from all lists like this:

```
element  |   list
-----------------
  O            1 
  V            1
  R            1
  M            1
  Y            1
  I            2
  Q            2
  L            2
  J            2
  A            2
  ...
```

You could run a query like the following to figure out which elements appear how many times in the lists:

```
SELECT element, count(element) as cnt FROM table, (SELECT distinct(element) as dst from table) as table2
WHERE element = table2.dst
GROUP BY element 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

You can also run a query to find all lists that contain your elements of choice. Here is the query to find all lists that contain `D`, `N` and `T`:

```
SELECT COUNT(element), list FROM table WHERE element IN ('D', 'N', 'T')
GROUP BY list
HAVING COUNT(element) = 3;
```